# MongoDB 2D geospatial max bounds, and possibly index benefit negation?

Tags: mongodb

We're migrating an app over to Mongo and I'd like to use the geospatial 2d index.

However, the coordinates we're storing aren't longitude/latitude and could potentially range from -1,000,000 to 1,000,000. Most of our users likely never have coordinates outside of -100,000 - 100,000 but we need to allow for the possibility.

- I can't find documentation on what the maximum bounds are for 2d geospatial indexes. What is the hard limit?
- Would a 2d index with that much of a range negate the performance benefit of using a geospatial index?

Right now we're simply storing the coords as an x/z int and with a standard index on those our query speeds are fairly solid so it's not a must-have but the `$near` and any other diskspace/performance gains would be nice.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for here. There should not be a hard limit on the values that are being indexed other than the restriction of the BSON type used for storage of the field value. Additionally, `$near` queries or equivalent are going to return the "nearest" 100 results or otherwise restricted by `max_distance` from the point (or otherwise). So this could be an answer (in a way) but I am really not seeing the question here, therefore why this is not an answer.

Comment: It's been suggested to me that the index performance will suffer when having to look up coordinates in very high ranges, like x:68000 z:89000